# QueryDSL: How can I create a predicate from a case expression?

Tags: java, querydsl

Using QueryDSL, I want to create a `Predicate` from a case expression that returns boolean expressions:

```
public static Predicate examplePredicate(NumberPath<Integer> typePath, DateTimePath<Date> timestampPath) {
    final Expression<Boolean> expr = typePath
        .when(0).then(timestampPath.lt(currentTimestamp()))
        .when(1).then(timestampPath.goe(currentTimestamp()))
        .otherwise(false);
    // How can I create a predicate from expr?
}
```

All `then` clauses of the case expression return `BooleanExpression`s - which implements `Predicate` - but the `expr` itself is of type `Expression<Boolean>`.

How can I create a `Predicate` (probably a `BooleanExpression`) from such a case expression?

Comment: From a quick look at the api, doesn't `BooleanExpression` have a constructor you can use, I.E. `BooleanExpression(Expression<Boolean> mixin) `?

Comment: @Robert Bain: Yes, but `BooleanExpression` is abstract.

Comment: Ah, right enough. Out of curiosity, why do you want this as a Predicate?

Comment: @Robert Bain: I want to use it in a join condition.

Comment: I think you could use a `CaseBuilder` E.G. `new CaseBuilder().when(typePath.intValue().eq(0)).then(timestampPath.lt(currentTimestamp()))...`

Comment: @RobertBain Indeed it returns a `BooleanExpression` (and therefore a `Predicate`). The generated SQL is not exactly the same, but I'll use it as a workaround anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`CaseBuilder`](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/latest/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/types/dsl/CaseBuilder.html) as follows:

```
new CaseBuilder()
.when(typePath.intValue().eq(0))
.then(timestampPath.lt(currentTimes‌​tamp()))
...
```

As noted in the comments to the original question, this generates different SQL to that generated by the original code extract but performs the desired function.